# Spring JPA with criteria builder convert timestamp with timezone to local time with given time zone

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am using PostgreSQL as db, i have a timestamptz column
I want to convert it into given timezone.

```
select 
  shipment0_.estimated_delivery_date_time at time zone 'IST'
from 
  shipment shipment0_
```

is the query, 
How can I implement it using JPA criteria with timezone as a user input.
I cannot use native query or JPQL since I already have other filters using criteria API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this blog post https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-functions-multiple-parameters-jpql-hibernate/

Managed to register a custom function using MetadataBuilderContributor